# Detection of real object using camera. Possibilities of finding real objects using camera

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am developing a project in robotics using android camera. The robot can move and clean the surface if any objects are found in the path. I am stuck in detection of objects in the path, I am not using any sensors to find the distance between the camera and the objects. I am only using a camera to find the objects in the path. I don't want to find out shape, type, color of object in the path. small objects in the path can be ignored such as sand , grass etc. There should not be any big objects in the path (in the marked portion of the figure below)

[image]

While detecting objects using camera paintings, shadows, are detected as objects. From the above figure the music symbol is detected as an object. Is there is any paid or open source library to find out real object detection using camera (it will be more helpful if it is usable in Java or c++). I have tried opencv, javacv, jhlabs,jjil, aviary sdk, jiu, imagemagic, etc. But no where i can find an exact solution for my need. If anybody working with this image processing please suggest me what i can do in real object detection using android camera. If it is not possible please give me an explanation why it was not possible.

The possibilities i have tried:

1. Face Recognition algorithm (feature detection) :- Face detection algorithm based on matching a pattern.   Which is not applicable in this case. ie, here the object may be anything or in any shape. There is no pattern for matching.
2. Object recognition : Object recognition is also doing the same this matching with the patten. I don't wanted to recognize the object, just wanted to find out their is an object in the marked portion in the image and it is a real object (ie, not any floor paintings, shadows , etc..).
3. Edge Detection : I have tried different edge detection algorithms but which is also not accurate solution for me. ie, paintings and shadows having edges so we can't assume the edges we found are real objects.

Comment: Did you solve this? Have you tried to find common images from distorted images. It is easy to implement a gaussian blur since it is just an average of the surrounding pixels put directly into a window matrix? Other distortions aren't too difficult either. As for real time, you might slow the bot down when it finds something and process what you find and then continue. Try http://www.amazon.com/dp/013168728X/?tag=stackoverfl08-20. Sorry, I've done my work in Java.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will check this and i will share the results here. I am having some projects other-than this now, when i will become free i will check this.

Answer (score 4):

> If anybody working with this image processing please suggest me what i can do in real object detection using android camera. If it is not possible please give me an explanation why it was not possible.

Real time, on the fly object detection is an area of intense research.

Right now, our existing algorithms are only capable pattern matching, and looking for pre defined images within the camera frame.

The problem with real world detection is that the real world is too... real. You have lots of variations of any kind of object or item, and it is impossible for a single library to provide detection for them. Real world detection is only plausible through extensive data generation and training via machin learning, which requires more processing and battery power than most mobile devices can provide.

Comment: Thanks Raghav Sood, Please let me know if you find any possibilities regarding this..

Answer (score 2):

You might want to get familiar with techniques called structure from motion. If You have  series of pictures from the same camera, taken in short intervals, You could acquire some 3D informations about the scene on the pictures. Unluckily, I do not know of any library that would do this for You out of the box, but it's a pretty popular problem, so some searching might give you a ready solution.

Comment: Thanks morynicz for the information. I have searched structure from motion, awesome concept dude.

Comment: Hi morynicz, i just findout some samples of structre from motion in nadroid. check this demo : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.boofcv.android . Sources : https://github.com/FedeCamposeco/Android-SfM-client , https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofAndroidDemo.

Answer (score 1):

Did a lot off image analysis in video surveillance. First you need to define what is a success rate you need. If you are trying all of this on one Image than you are probably aware that this is not going to work :). On the video analysis you can search for some good algorithms for motion detection which are  going to give you  all moving objects on some background. You have a more difficult case where you are moving. You somehow need to model that background. If you want your robot to move on some colorfull background like for example paint, how are you going to know what is a object without depth perception. Maybe try something with shadows but no. And after all, these algorithms are all so intensive, the better the result the more CPU power you need. Android is not meant for that. You can do some simple processing but you want way to much than it is currently possible.

Bottom line is that you need to adjust your needs/resources a little bit more.

PS. If you manage to do this after all like you first said, we will see you on some yacht with some gorgeous models

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Thanks Marko Lazic. Please let me know if you tried any libraries of image processing. It's heart-breaking to think that i'll miss the yacht ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the camera is parallel to the ground and the ground is usually flat, you could estimate the distance of the objects considering its position on the video frame. Hogher the distance of the object, more to the top of the image it will be. In fact you can estimate a value in meters with some noise, like us human beings.

I think your problem of recognizing "real objects" can be translated to: "Find not flat (to the ground) visual elements, in other words, find objects with some height".

Have you considered a stereovision approach? Using two cameras you can deal with three-dimensional issues more properly.

Comment: Thanks Marvin for your answer.. Finding distance is a solution.. But the problem is we cant estimate the distance from objects to camera in android.. There is no sensor to find the distance in android..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use more than one camera.....giving a two dimensional view to image .....hope it would help ....

Comment: Thanks swap. Please let me if u found anything regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

you can train or use Pre train model Deep Learning model using Tensorflow, and Keras first you have to collect object data as much as possible make sure it collects from the field then try to train the model with different architecture as your need satisfy.you can tune Hyperparameters and convert model into Tensorflow lite to pack mode in android app.

for more reference, you can visit [tenserflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

This is the easiest way I found for addressing computer vision problem.